# Deactivate dead OCS 2007 R2 Edge Server?

Tags: lync, failed, ms-office-communicator

I'm having a surprising issue where our old OCS 2007 R2 Edge server died of hardware failure (no backup) in the middle of our move to Lync.  How can I forcefully remove the Edge server from the organization without being able to deactivate the role from the server itself?

I've noticed the correct procedure for uninstalling OCS 2007 R2 is as follows:

If you are removing an Edge Server, a Mediation Server, an Archiving Server, or a Monitoring Server, remove the Office Communications Server 2007 R2 components in the following sequence:

```
Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2
Edge Server Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2 
Mediation Server Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2 
Archiving Server Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2
Monitoring Server Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2 
Core Components Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2
Unified Communications Managed API 2.0 Core Redistribution package
```

And to deactivate an Edge server:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572832(v=office.13).aspx

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had to contact MS business critical support who toyed with ADSI Edit to remove the old server from the infrastructure.  Really no easy solution to this.

Answer (score -1):

You can deactivate the Edge Server using the Admin Tools on an OCS server joined to the domain. You don't have to do it from the server itself.

Comment: This is not true.  You are unable to do it using the admin tools straight from the OCS server unless the Edge server is already uninstalled.